# Origin of Church encodings

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, lambda-calculus, ho.history-overview

In which paper did Alonzo Church first describe [Church encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_numerals)? I can't find any articles that actually cite the paper, but I am interested in reading it.

Comment: Many of definability results about lambda calculus are by Kleene and Rosser, Chruch's students. I think there should be references in Barendregt's book.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be this one:

Church, A. (1941) The Calculi of Lambda-Conversion. Annals of Mathematics Studies
No. 6, Princeton University Press.